# How to assign to a new array an array of objects?

Tags: java, spring

I can't figure out how I would do the ff.

I have the ff. Payload

```
   {
    "code": null,
    "message": null,
    "recCtrlOut": {
    },
    "acctSumm": [
        {
            "acctBasic": {
                "acctType": "SV",
                "acctId": "123",
                },
            "acctBasic": {
                "acctType": "SV",
                "acctId": "321",
                }
}
]
        
}
```

And I just want to get the acctId params and assign it to a new plain array of accountIds. How do I do it in Spring/Java?. Thanks

Comment: Your JSON is invalid

Comment: ok, i updated it , didnt noticed i missed the square brackets when redacting the payload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using json path. Library can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path). E.g. say you had json like this:

```
{
  "code": null,
  "message": null,
  "recCtrlOut": {
  },
  "acctSumm": [
    {
      "acctBasic": {
        "acctType": "SV",
        "acctId": "123"
      }
    },
    {
      "acctBasic": {
        "acctType": "SV",
        "acctId": "321"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Actual code would be something like:

```
List<String> ids = JsonPath.read(json, "$.acctSumm[*].acctBasic.acctId");
```

The above list will now hold:

```
["123","321"]
```

If you wanna learn json path syntax, you could try using [this](https://jsonpath.com/) online tool. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath) is also a guide to help you get started with json path.